# "Error: no label provider for Tomcat v9.0 at localhost"

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, server

I'm trying to simply attach a Tomcat server to my Eclipse project, however every time I try to add a server I get an error in the server view section of Eclipse. The server info shows up in the project explorer, but you cannot run/edit the server from the server view.

This is what the error looks like:
[image]

Even right clicking inside of the server view just says, "Clean Tomcat work directory..." and "Browse deployment location..." rather than creating a new server.

My Tomcat installation works fine, checking localhost:8080, so it must be something with Eclipse.

I'm using Tomcat v9.0 as well as jdk 1.8.0_241

Comment: And what version of Eclipse?

Comment: 2019-12 (4.14.0)

Comment: How was it installed? This isn't normal.

Comment: How was Eclipse installed? From their website, it is the Java EE variant. Here is the link:https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2019-12/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-developers

Comment: Unfortunately with that release of Eclipse, OpenJDK, and Tomcat, I'm not having the same issue. Have you installed anything after downloading?

Comment: I did install Subclipse as well as Spring Tool Suite through the Eclipse marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error create new workspace and add your projects to that workspace.
This error is just related with current workspace only, so by creating new workspace in eclipse you can add tomcat server and continue your work with no issue.